# Issue With Comparing Strings In C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to compare a string with another string and if they match I want the text "That is correct" to output but I can't seem to get it working.

Here is the code:

```
int main () 
{
    char * password = "Torroc";
    char * userInput;

    printf("Please enter your password: ");
    scanf("%s", userInput);

    if (strcmp(password, userInput) == 0) {
        printf("That is correct!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `char * userInput;` --> `char userInput[16];`

Comment: `scanf` into an unset pointer? Who suggested you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, userInput pointer does not have provision to hold the string that you are about to pass using the scanf call. You need to allocate space for the cstring userInput in your stack, before you try to save/assign any string to it. So...

You need to change the following code:

```
char * userInput;
```

to:

```
char userInput[200];
```

Here, 200 is just an arbitrary value. In your case, please select the max. length of the string + 1 for the (\0).

Comment: I have explained!

Comment: Opps! my mistake, typo.

Comment: Also provide the limit to `scanf()` to avoid potential buffer overflows: `scanf("%199s", userInput);` and check the return value of `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter characters you need to store the characters somewhere.

```
char* userInput;
```

is an uninitialized pointer.

So first you declare an array for your input

```
char userInput[128];
```

Now when reading from the keyboard you need to make sure the user does not enter more characters than 127 + one for \0 because it would overwrite the stack so best way to read from the keyboard is to use fgets, it also good to check the return value, if the user simply pressed ENTER without writing anything fgets returns NULL.

```
if (fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin) != NULL) {
```

Now you have the string that the user entered plus the end of line character. To remove it you can do something like

```
   char* p = strchr(userInput,'\n');
   if ( p != NULL ) *p = '\0';
```

Now you can compare the strings

```
   if (strcmp(password, userInput) == 0) {
      puts("That is correct!");
   }
```

Comment: Note that `scanf("%s", userInput)` has different semantics than `fgets()`. `scanf` with a `%s` format reads a whitespace-delimited word. `fgets` reads an entire line. The OP needs to decide which he wants. (Normally passwords should be allowed to include whitespace, but that's an application behavior issue, not a C issue.) Something like `scanf("%20s", userInput)` can avoid a buffer overrun.

Comment: @KeithThompson I find fgets easier to use, u can always use sscanf on the result if more parsing power is needed

Comment: Another idiom for zapping a newline is `userInput[strcspn(userInput, "\n")] = '\0';`.

Comment: there's also `strtok(userInput, "\n");` although that is not so good on the thread-safety front

Comment: @M.M: threads are not the only issue: the internal state should be thread local, but reentrency is an issue even on single threaded programs: nested uses of `strtok()` cause failures that are sometimes difficult to locate.

Answer (score 0):

When you think about "a string" in C, you should see it as an array of `char`'s.

Let me use the identifier `s` instead of `userInput` for brevity:

```
       0   1   2   3   4   5         9
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+-- --+---+
s -> | p | i | p | p | o | \0| ... |   |
     +---+---+---+---+---+---+-- --+---+
```

is what

```
char s[10] = "pippo";
```

would create.

In other words, it's a block of memory where the first 6 *bytes* have been initialized as shown. There is no `s` *variable* anywhere.

Instead, declaring a `char *` like in

```
 char *s;
```

would create a variable that can hold a pointer to `char`:

```
  +------------+
 s| 0xCF024408 |      <-- represent an address  
  +------------+
```

If you think this way, you notice immediately that doing:

```
 scanf("%s",s);
```

only make sense in the first case, where there is (hopefully) enough memory to hold the string.

In the second case, the variable `s` points to some random address and you will end up writing something into an unknown memory area.

For completeness, in cases like:

```
 char *s = "pippo";
```

you have the following situation in memory:

```
                 0   1   2   3   4   5  
               +---+---+---+---+---+---+       Somewhere in the
  0x0B320080   | p | i | p | p | o | \0|   <-- readonly portion 
               +---+---+---+---+---+---+       of memory


  +------------+        a variable pointing
 s| 0x0B320080 |    <-- to the address where
  +------------+        the string is
```

You can make `s` pointing somewhere else but you can't change the content of the string pointed by `s`.